# GRAB utility invisible in FINDER

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I use the utility GRAB occasionally.  It does not show in the utility list under applications in Finder.  However, I know it is there because when I search I find it -

How can I make it appear on the list?

Answer (score 1):

It's on a folder called Utilities inside Applications.